# Adding firestore document returns "Timestamp is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, quasar-framework

From my Quasar app I'm trying to insert a document to firestore collection. It works just fine, but when I try to insert document with specific field type (like timestamp) I get an error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: boot_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.db.Timestamp is not a constructor"
```

**boot file**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import "firebase/firestore"

const config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
}
let firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = firebaseApp.firestore()

export { firebaseApp, db }
```

**Vue component**

```
<template>
   <div>
       <q-card @click="do()">
       </q-card>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import {firebaseApp, db} from 'boot/firebase'
export default {
  methods:{
    do(){
        db.collection("clt").add({
            dt: new db.Timestamp(42, 0) 
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```

For the moment i have to use duty workaround like

```
dt: new db.app.firebase_.firestore.Timestamp(42, 0)
```

But I don't understand why Timestamp cannot be called from db object directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code boils down to:

```
new firebase.firestore().Timestamp(42, 0)
```

If you look in the documentation of the [`Timestamp` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), the type is not defined on the `firestore` instance, but on its static namespace.

To create a new `Timestamp` you need:

```
new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(42, 0)
```

So your workaround is actually the proper solution :)